# Update Duplicate value in second row if found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have come across a problem. I have a table where some rows will have one column data duplicated. However other columns are unique.
What I am after is when it detects that this is the second row and a previous row might already have the same column value, in that instance just add some number to that columns value.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempt') is not null drop table #tempt;
create table #tempt(
  cmpName varchar(50),
  cmpCode varchar(50)
)
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-ABC234FG Ont','252750023862545';
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-XDDF34FG Ont','252750057762511';
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-POC624AG Ont','252750057762789';
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-ABC234FG Ont','252750057762511';

cmpName             cmpCode
cmp-ABC234FG Ont    252750023862545
cmp-ABC234FG Ont    252750057762511
cmp-POC624AG Ont    252750057762789
cmp-XDDF34FG Ont    252750057762511
```

in the above example int first 2 rows column cmName has duplicate values. What I am after is the second row should have any char appended to its value so that it will become a unique row .eg.

```
cmpName             cmpCode
cmp-ABC234FG Ont    252750023862545
cmp-ABC234FG Ont-2  252750057762511
```

Can some kind soul help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no row order in SQL table, so please provide the ordering criteria to call some row as the first, and some as the second.

Comment: There is a simple way to do that using cursor but it will slow and not suggested. If you want that then I might post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As astentx stated, you'll need a column to order by or decide which row you want to update. In this example I used `cmpCode`:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempt') is not null drop table #tempt;
create table #tempt(
  cmpName varchar(50),
  cmpCode varchar(50)
)
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-ABC234FG Ont','252750023862545';
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-XDDF34FG Ont','252750057762511';
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-POC624AG Ont','252750057762789';
insert into #tempt select 'cmp-ABC234FG Ont','252750057762511';

;with cte as(
select row_number() over(partition by cmpName order by cmpCode) rn,
        *
from #tempt
)

update cte
set cmpName = concat(cmpName,'-',rn)
where rn > 1

select *
from #tempt
```

This will take into consideration there might be more than two records with the same `cmName` value.

Comment: `cmpName - rn` will create a new group which already can be a exists in that column for other rows in `#temp` table.

Comment: Certainly something to take into consideration if this isn't a one-time update. If there is the potential for a scenario like that then you may need to look at using some sort of GUID instead of `rn`.